# Error trying to create many routed events in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, routed-events

I'm trying to create a wpf class that inherits from Label, and registers two new custom routed events (typeOneEvent and typeTwoEvent). However, when using this derived control in the xaml designer, it will only see typeOneEvent , and not typeTwoEvent (throws a "member is not recognized or is not accessible error"). If I switch the order they are declared in, it only sees typeTwoEvent. It's as if Only one new routed event can by created.

```
    public static readonly RoutedEvent EventTypeFirst = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("TypeOneEvent", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(CustomObject));

    public static readonly RoutedEvent EventTypeSecond = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("TypeTwoEvent", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(CustomObject));
```

The weirdest part is that while that error prevents the project from building on a friends computer running VS2012, my VS2012 will build the project (even though the error still shows in the error list) and will even run the program (which has both events working just fine).

I've created two projects where this is true, normally I might ignore this since the program runs, but this a multi-person project. Can anyone shed some light on what's going on?

Comment: Your project isn't on a network drive is it? Is it on your local drive?

Comment: The project is on a local drive, as I know to steer clear of network drives with wpf/visual studio.